# Change monitor refresh rate for 4k monitor

Tags: intel-graphics, monitor, xrandr, external-monitor

I try to change the external monitor refresh rate for my IIYAMA PROLITE X4071UHSU-B1 Monitor on a XNG p406 Laptop. I'm using the internal Intel GPU.

`xrandr` gives me:

```
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+961 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   (...)

DP1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 878mm x 485mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  30.00*   29.97  
   1920x2160     60.00  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2048x1152     60.00 
   (...)
```

So, 60Hz should be available, but is not used.

So I try to switch to 60 hz with `xrandr --output DP1 --rate 60`. But nothing happens. No output in the console, no flickering or something. And xrandr gives the same output like above.

Am I doing something wrong?

My Ubuntu: 
16.04 With 4.7.2-040702-generic kernel

Comment: How is the monitor connected - HDMI or DisplayPort? If you're using HDMI there might be a chance that the cable (and the port of your GPU) must be at least version 2.0. At least that's what big screen TV's require to display 4K at 60Hz

Comment: It`s connected to the mini display port...

Comment: Run `cat ~/.config/monitors.xml` and see the specific monitor. What is the rate for that monitor in that file? For example **<rate>60</rate>**

Comment: Ok, it was set to 30 in that file. I changed it to 60. Now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jiipeezz pointed me to the right direction:
I edited the file `~/.config/monitors.xml` with the command `sudo gedit ~/.config/monitors.xml` and changed `<rate>30</rate>` to `<rate>60</rate>` and rebooted. Now it works, xrandr output is:

```
DP1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 878mm x 485mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00    29.97  
   1920x2160     60.00  
   2560x1440     59.95
```